# Get/set variable inside if statement

Tags: javascript

I have a small example to define and assign to `arr` array.

```
var arr;

if (arr = [1]) { // arr is an array here, it contains 1 element
    console.log(arr.length); // 1
}
```

Then, I want to get `length` of the array

```
var arr;

// arr is an array here, but why cannot I assign to length property?
if (arr = [1] && arr.length) { 
    console.log(arr.length);
}
```

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: var arr;

// arr is an array here, but why cannot I assign to length property?
if ((arr = [1]) && arr.length) { 
    console.log(arr.length);
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var arr;

// arr is an array here, but why cannot I assign to length property?
if (arr = [1] && arr.length) { 
    console.log(arr.length);
}
```

fails due to [operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence). `&&` has higher precedence than the assignment `=`, so it is evaluated first.

`[1] && arr.length` expression consists of an array literal and the `arr.length` expression. And `arr.length` fails, since `arr` is undefined at that point.

References:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence

Answer (score 1):

In this line:

```
if (arr = [1] && arr.length)
```

You assigned the array to arr and at the same time tried to check for the length. Since JS does not know yet that `arr` contains an array at this point it throws an exception when trying to access the length property.

For comparison, this does not throw an exception:

```
if (arr = [1]) {
    if (arr.length) {
        console.log(arr.length);
    }
}
```

Because upon reaching the second condition check, JS already knows that `arr` is an array.

Answer (score 1):

your if should be like this `if ((arr = [1]) && arr.length)`

you need to give high precedence to array assignment part . to assign first then compare .

precedence is nothing but . which part code execute first based on operator precedence  so in your code  `&&` is higher precedence than assignment operator  `=` so while arr not assigned so it is undefined

```js
var arr;

// arr is an array here, but why cannot I assign to length property?
if ((arr = [1]) && arr.length) {
  console.log(arr.length);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

JS parses your `if` statement as

```
 if (arr = ([1] && arr.length)) {
```

The reason is that `&&` binds more tightly than the assignment operator. As a result, JS is trying to evaluate `[1] && arr.length` at a point in time where `arr` is not yet defined.

You need to write

```
if ((arr = [1]) && arr.length) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Assigning variable inside IF is a code smell.

```
var arr;
var x = 1;

if (arr = [1] && arr.length && x == 1) { 
    console.log(arr.length);
}
```

How does the if condition above look like? Most people may not aware your are assigning value to `arr` but think you are check if `arr == [1]`.

A better example:

```
var arr = [1];

if (arr.length > 0) { 
    console.log(arr.length);
}
```

Comment: You don't understand what I'm asking